# Rails convention to define a class used by my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Considering that I have a standard Rails directory structure in my project (the directory we get after a `rails new`) and that I have several controllers (`controllerA`, `controllerB`, `controllerC`, etc), where would be a good place to define a class that I want to use in all the controllers?

I was thinking about defining the class in `application_controller.rb` and then use it, another option is define it in a file inside the `models` folder and then `require` that file.

Is there a Rails convention for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a `services` directory under `app`, put your class in there, and be done with it. No need to do a require as Rails will find it automatically.

Do not define a class in your controller. Do not put a plain old ruby objects in your `models` folder.

Comment: I would add that Rails will find it automatically if the file's name correspond to the class inside defined in it. Example: file `app/controllers/services/twitter_fetcher.rb` should define the class `Services::TwitterFetcher`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your class in the `controllers/concerns` directory.

Comment: You could, buy why would you? Put the apples in the apples basket, and the oranges in the oranges basket. They're easier to find that way.